# Error Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: arrays, error-handling, undefined, uppercase

Having an array with strings, if a string starts with a letter I want to capitalize the letter, that's all.
I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase').
That's strange because the function map "sees" all values inside array which are well defined! So why the error?

```
function camelize(str){
    let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g);
    let arr2 = arr.map(e => {
        if(/[a-z]/.test(e[0])) {
            return e[0].toUpperCase() + e.slice(1);
        }
        else {
            return e;
        }
    });
    return arr2.join('').replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '');
}

camelize('#hello4&- john'); 
VM19168:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')
    at <anonymous>:5:16
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at camelize (<anonymous>:3:17)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = '#hello4&- john'.toLowerCase().split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g);
console.log(arr)
console.log(arr[0])
console.log(arr[0][0])
```

Here is the problem:
The first element of an empty string is `undefined`.

You should filter out the empty strings before calling `map`.

Comment: Eureka `''[0] === undefined`
true